# function evalclusters from Statistics toolbox not found in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to use the function evalclusters from the statistics toolbox in matlab, but matlab is unable to find the function when I call it.

help evalclusters
returns 'evalclusters not found.'

The statistics toolbox is installed [license('test','statistics_toolbox') returns '1'].

Thanks!

Comment: What version are you using? Probably that matlab version did not include `evalclusters` and it was added later.

Comment: Version R2013a(8.1.0.604). Will try to update to newest version.

Comment: Updating did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evalclusters` was added with Matlab 2013b and extended with 2014a, it is not available in Matlab 2013a.

In case upgrading Matlab is not an option, current Octave Statistics package includes it as well. (Open-Source alternative to Matlab which basically uses the same syntax)